# jquery datepicker with $.post() in yii framework

Tags: jquery, http-post, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use the jquery datepicker. What I need to do is to call an action search that return the result with the selected date.
The problem is that I have the html response correct but I don't know how to render it. I still always in the same page.

here is the jquery post code:

```
function(formated, dates) {
                    $.post(
                        'diary',
                        {'date' : formated },
                        'html');

                },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method? You can use it to replace the contents of an element in your page (e.g. a `<div>` placed specifically for this purpose) with the HTML that gets returned by the AJAX call.

Take a look at the examples on the jQuery documentation page to see if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Yep thanks.
here is how I solved it.

```
$('#result').load('diary', {'date' : formated});
```